# Using grep to find two or more vowels in a row

Tags: text-processing, grep

So far I am using `grep -E '[aeiou]{2}' /usr/share/dict/american-english`. This is giving me two vowels, but I want them to be only vowels in a row, like "tooth", "beer", etc.

So I want to use grep to get a word with a vowel, but only if that vowel is followed by the same vowel. Like, I want to find tooth, I want to see if I can write a command that will look for the first `o` and see the next character is a `o`. Is that more clear?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
grep -E '([aeiou])\1' infile
```

With parenthesis we capture a group match where they are accessed by the `\1` as back-reference for the first group (if there were more groups, then `\2` for the second and so on upto `\9` are allowed). so any single vowels character was matched in `(....)` (`[aeiou]` means match one of `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` or `u`) with `\1` we checks it's duplicate itself or not.